# Sum of product of two sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_n\}$ be such that $\tfrac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^m a_n$ converges absolutely to some finite constant $a_0$. The $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\tfrac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^m \tfrac{a_n}{n}$ is trivially upper bounded by $a_0$. Does there exist a tighter upper bound?

Comment: Observe that $\frac{a_1+...+a_{m-1}+a_m}{m}=\frac{m-1}{m}\frac{a_1+...+a_{m-1}}{m-1}+\frac{a_m}{m}$. Therefore $\frac{a_m}{m}\to0$. By [Stolz-Cesaro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) the average of the $a_m/m$ tends to the same limit $0$.

Comment: Let $A_m=\sum_{n=1}^{m}a_n$. By summation by parts
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{a_n}{n} = \frac{A_m}{m}+\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{A_n}{n(n+1)}$$
and by denoting as $M=\sup_{m}\frac{A_m}{m}$ we have
$$ \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{a_n}{n}\leq M\cdot\frac{1+\log m}{m}\to 0.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks! This answers my question as the sequence I am considering admits a reasonable bound $M$. I think one can, in fact, improve $M$ to approach $a_0$. Correct me if I am wrong there.

Comment: @sunwarm I am not quite sure how your argument may work. It seems  Stolz-Ceasaro theorem states that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\tfrac{\delta u_n}{\delta v_n} = c $ implies  $\lim_{m\to \infty}\tfrac{u_m}{v_m} = c$. If we let $\delta u_n = a_n$ and $\delta v_n = n$, then $\lim_{m\to \infty}\tfrac{\sum_{n=1}^{m} a_n}{\sum_{n =1}^{m} n} = c$.

Comment: @SoumyaBasu No, I am applying Stolz-Cesaro to the average of $a_m/m$. Therefore what you are calling $\delta u_n=a_m/m$ and $\delta v_n=1$. Since $\delta u_n/\delta v_n=a_m/m\to0$, then $\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{m}a_n/n }{m}\to0$. My argument is actually the only one so far that proves the convergence.

Comment: @sunwarm Thank you for the clarification. I see your argument now. I agree that your solution is the only one that works unconditionally.

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider the sequence with $a_1=1$ and $a_i=0$ for $i>1$. Then we have $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^ma_n=0$$
and
$$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{a_n}{n}=0$$
as well so there is no tighter upper bound.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, for the special case you mention, $a_0 = 0$ is the best bound we can obtain. However, I am concerned with general cases. In particular, when $a_0 > 0$ I wanted to understand if the summation converges to $0$.